# Question on coefficient of $\exp(H_n).\log(H_n)$ in Lagarias equivalence of RH

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

In [page 197, Equivalents of the Riemann Hypothesis Vol 1](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108178228), the following statement caught my eye

> There is an editorial comment in [102] that includes an observation by
> the GCHQ Problem Solving Group. They contest that one could replace the
> number 2 in inequality (7.94) by any constant $K > 1$ at the cost of having to
> check more cases by hand when $K$ is close to one. An example is cited: when
> $K = 1.2$ one needs to verify inequality (7.94) for $1 \leq n \leq 10^6$.

referring the inequality 7.94

> $\sigma(n) \leq H_n +2\exp(H_n) \log(H_n)$, $n \geq 1$,

and the reference [102](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145148) being

> [102] J. C. Lagarias and W. Janous, A generous bound for divisor sums: problem 10949, Amer. Math. Monthly 111 (2004), 264–265.

According to [An Elementary Problem Equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008177) by J. C. Lagarias, $K = 1$ is equivalent to RH. I understand the claim is not that RH can be proved by checking more cases by hand, but I want to understand what are the methods by which $K$ can be improved to any $1 + \epsilon$ by checking more cases? What are the barriers that prevent it from  proving that $K \leq 1$ by checking for more cases?

Edit: Edited my question with more details after looking at the answer by @Charles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** By an inequality due to Robin (see (2.2) in Lagarias's paper),
$$\sigma(n)\leq e^\gamma n\log\log n+\frac{n}{\log\log n},\qquad n\geq 3.$$
By Lemma 3.1 in Lagarias's paper, we also know that
$$\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)\geq e^\gamma n\log\log n,\qquad n\geq 3.$$
Combining these two estimates, we infer that
$$\sigma(n)\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{(\log\log n)^2}\right)\exp(H_n)\log(H_n),\qquad n\geq 3.$$
The fraction on the right hand side tends to zero (effectively), confirming the observation by the GCHQ Problem Solving Group. Explicitly, given any $\varepsilon>0$, we have
$$\sigma(n)\leq(1+\varepsilon)\exp(H_n)\log(H_n),\qquad n\geq\exp\exp(\varepsilon^{-1/2}).$$

**2.** The barrier to prove Lagarias's inequality is the same as the barrier to prove the Riemann Hypothesis, since these two statements are equivalent. It is a difficult problem, and perhaps it is even undecidable from the ZFC axioms (of course most of us believe it is decidable).

Comment: +1. Prashanth, this is the answer to accept.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @GHfromMO . It's very clear for me now. Also, shouldn't there be $\exp(\gamma)$ in the denominator of the fraction on the RHS ?  Your next statement that it tends to zero is still valid as $\exp(\gamma)$ is a constant, but I'm just making sure my understanding is correct as I don't really have a math background.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the attempt of proof of some statement (not necessarily RH) is decidable from ZFC axioms?

Comment: @PrashanthNCR: The third display can be strengthened by including a factor of $e^\gamma$ in the denominator. Note that $e^\gamma$ exceeds $1$. In fact this factor could be enlarged slightly, because in Robin's bound there is a constant $0.6482$ present in front of the fraction. I omitted these constants for elegance of presentation.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: If ZFC is consistent, then there is no algorithm that could tell about every statement in ZFC whether it is decidable or not from the ZFC axioms.

Comment: RH is a complex number problem. The theory of complex numbers is complete,, therefore there is either a proof of RH or a proof of its negation (analytic). On the other hand, it could be independent in Peano Arithmetic

Comment: @EGME I don't think it is known that RH is decidable within ZFC. Note also that the solvability of any diophantine equation can be formulated within the theory of complex numbers, and there are diophantine equations whose solvability is not decidable within ZFC (assuming ZFC is consistent).

Comment: As I understood from this [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79685/can-the-riemann-hypothesis-be-undecidable), if RH is false, it can be provably false because of Robin-Ramanujan inequalities

Answer (score 6):

The case $K=1$ is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis. [1] The GCHQ Problem Solving Group is not claiming that RH can be proved by checking a finite number of cases of this problem. I don't know what the barriers are that prevent it, though; I don't even know the method they used to extend $K$.

[1] Jeffrey C. Lagarias, [An Elementary Problem Equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008177), *American Mathematical Monthly* **109** (2002), pp. 534–543.

Comment: Among those $n$ that I could reach, the largest value of $\frac{\sigma(n)-H_n}{\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)}$ is $\approx0.987238$, attained at $n=12$

Comment: Thanks @Charles , I understood that they are not claiming RH can be proved by checking a finite number of cases, I wanted to understand how can we reduce K to any 1+ϵ by checking more cases and why can't we go beyond $1$ ? Perhaps, I should edit my question.

Comment: Well for $K<1$ it’s simply false: combining Thm. 2.2 and L. 3.2 in Lagarias’s paper, it follows immediately that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sigma(n)-H_n}{\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sigma(n)}{\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)}\ge1$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Is any $n$ known with $\frac{\sigma(n)-H_n}{\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)}>\frac{\sigma(12)-H_{12}}{\exp(H_{12})\log(H_{12})}$?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე sure, take the 100th number from this sequence: https://oeis.org/A004490 and you'll get $\approx 0.9929$

Comment: @AlexanderKalmynin Wow, thanks! But why 100th? Is this the smallest one? What is the next one? Can you give a reference for a study of the "record breakers" like that? Are they all colossally abundant? Do you think it makes sense to ask a separate question about it here on MO?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე  it is well known that if there exists an number that do not obey Lagarias inequality, then it must be a colossally abundant number.

Comment: @PrashanthNCR I became curious about the sequence $a_k$ defined by requiring that for each $k$, $a_{k+1}$ is the smallest natural number with $L(a_{k+1})>L(a_k)$, where $L(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)-H_n}{\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)}$, starting with $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$. It seems that $a_3=6$, $a_4=12$ and $a_5$ is huge. By Alexander Kalmynin's example, $a_5$ does not exceed the 100th colossally abundant number. I wonder if $a_5$ is equal to it, and whether each $a_n$ is colossally abundant. How fast does this sequence grow?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Honestly, I don't remember the precise statement on colossal abundantness of these "record breakers", but Prashanth is probably right. I believe, some results of this type were also derived by Ramanujan. 100 here is pretty random, I chose it because 25th and 50th numbers from the list were not sufficient.

Comment: @AlexanderKalmynin I did some calculations with that. If my numerical approximations for $H_n$ are correct, the first colossally abundant number whose ratio exceeds that of $12$ is the 58th one ($\approx5.95\times10^{76}$). And in fact it seems that starting from the 29th colossally abundant number these ratios grow monotonously. I think I will ask a separate question about it.