# What is the smallest sequence $a_k$ with nondecreasing $\frac{\sigma(a_k)-H_{a_k}}{\exp(H_{a_k})\log(H_{a_k})}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

This is inspired by the [Question on coefficient of $\exp(H_n).\log(H_n)$ in Lagarias equivalence of RH](https://mathoverflow.net/q/401563/41291) , an answer and some comments there.

For $n\geqslant2$ denote
$$
L(n):=\frac{\sigma(n)-H_n}{\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)},
$$
where $\sigma$ is the divisor sum and $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

As Emil Jeřábek explains in one of the comments there, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}L(n)\geqslant1$. The result of Lagarias says that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to $L(n)\leqslant1$ for all $n$, so that there exists a sequence $a_k$ with $L(a_k)$ growing monotonously and $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=1$. Clearly there is a smallest such sequence: take $a_1=2$ and $a_{k+1}$ the smallest number $n$ with $L(n)\geqslant L(a_k)$.

Here are the few starting values (up to ten decimal places):
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
n & L(n)\\
\hline
\color{red} 2 &\color{red}{0.82546003} \\
 3 & 0.571499183 \\
\color{red} 4 &\color{red}{0.83408973} \\
 5 & 0.458908111 \\
\color{red} 6 &\color{red}{0.91966830} \\
 7 & 0.424541931 \\
 8 & 0.81094546 \\
 9 & 0.57778078 \\
 10 & 0.74961989 \\
 11 & 0.39656917 \\
\color{red}{12} &\color{red}{0.98723811} \\
 13 & 0.38886853 \\
 14 & 0.68121794 \\
 15 & 0.62448763 \\
 16 & 0.77143689 \\
 17 & 0.37810207 \\
 18 & 0.86099035 \\
 19 & 0.37404301 \\
 20 & 0.82141873 \\
\end{array}
$$
After that, I checked for $n$ up to more than one million, $L(n)$ never exceeds $L(12)$.

In a comment, Alexander Kalmynin indicated that $L(12)$ is exceeded by the 100th [Colossally Abundant Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number) (CAN in what follows). Searching through their list at OEIS [A004490](https://oeis.org/A004490) I found that the first CAN with $L$ exceeding $L(12)$ is the 58th one,
$$
2^9\cdot3^5\cdot5^3\cdot7^3\cdot11^2\cdot13^2\cdot17^2\cdot19\cdot23\cdot\ldots\cdot167
$$
(all primes in between, $\approx5.94632\times10^{76}$). In fact it seems that, denoting the $k$th CAN by $C_k$, $L(C_k)$ grows monotonously starting from $C_{29}$. The line through $(C_k,L(C_k))$, $k\leqslant150$, looks like

[image]

Thus one such sequence is $2=C_1$, $4$, $6=C_2$, $12=C_3$, $C_{58}$, $C_{59}$, ..., $C_{150}$, ...

But is the sequence of $L(C_k)$ really monotonously growing? Is it the smallest such sequence? Is in fact $C_{58}$ the smallest $n$ with $L(12)<L(n)$? Can there be some $m\ne n$ with $L(m)=L(n)$? And, is there an efficient method to check all this computationally?