# Platonic Truth and 1st Order Logic - Take 2

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

As an algebraist, I have some strong intuitions about what it means for an algebraic result to be true.  In particular, my intuition would lead me to believe that if I cannot construct a counter-example to a claim, then the claim must be true.  This is what motivated [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258132/platonic-truth-and-1st-order-predicate-logic), where it became clear that my intuition needed some tweaking.  (In other words, in some contexts it just doesn't hold true!)  The answers given there are excellent, and I recommend people read them before continuing.

So here is a follow-up question to see just how far we can take the intuition.

Let $T_0$ be the theory ${\rm PA}$ over a countable language.  Let $T_1$ be the extended theory obtained by adding as new axioms all $\Pi_1^0$ statement which are independent of ${\rm PA}$.  This new theory is consistent and sound, assuming that the standard model of the natural numbers exists.

I would guess that this new theory $T_1$ is already not effectively computable.  At any rate, suppose now that we let $T_2$ be the extended theory of $T_1$ obtained by adding as new axioms all $\Pi_2^0$ statement which are independent of $T_1$.

Is $T_2$ consistent?  If so, is the theory $T_n$ (defined in the obvious recursive way) consistent?  If so, is $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}T_n$ the true theory of the standard model?

If $T_2$ is not consistent, is there some natural way to fix the problem?

Finally, what happens if we repeat these ideas for ${\rm ZFC}$ instead?

Comment: Perhaps it would help clarify the question to say that you are adding *all* independent $\Pi^0_1$ sentences as new axioms. (The word "any" could be misunderstood as allowing you to add any such axioms you like.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your theory is the same as the true arithmetic. In
particular, yes, it is consistent.

I claim that at stage $n$, your theory $T_n$ consists of PA plus
the collection of true $\Pi^0_n$ sentences (that is, true in the
standard model). This starts out true with $T_0$. If $T_n$ is like
that, then consider $T_{n+1}$. If $\psi$ is a true $\Pi^0_{n+1}$
statement, then in particular, it is consistent with $T_n$, since
both are true in the standard model. So either it is provable from
$T_n$, in which case it is already there, or else it is
independent, in which case you add it at stage $n+1$. Conversely,
if $\psi$ is a $\Pi^0_{n+1}$ statement that is independent of
$T_n$, then in particular, it asserts $\forall x\ \phi(x)$, where
$\phi(x)$ is $\Sigma_n$. Since $\psi$ is true in a model of $T_n$,
it follows that $\phi(m)$ must hold of every standard $m$, since if $\phi(m)$ failed then $\neg\phi(m)$ would be a true $\Pi^0_n$ sentence and hence part of $T_n$, preventing $\psi$ from being consistent with $T_n$. So
$\psi$ is true.

Thus, by induction, you are adding all and only the true $\Pi^0_n$
statements at each stage, and you've got the theory of true
arithmetic.

Comment: Excellent.  What happens for ZFC if we try to do the same thing?

Comment: An essentially similar argument works with ZFC, if one has a strong enough meta theory. For example, if there is an $\omega$-model of ZFC, then you are again adding the true $\Pi^0_n$ sentences of arithmetic at stage $n$. But if ZFC is not arithmetically sound, for example, in a model of ZFC+$\neg$Con(ZFC), then things will go awry already at $T_2$, giving an inconsistent theory.

Comment: Supposing that there is an $\omega$-model of ZFC, are there any statements known to belong to $T_2$, such as $V=L$ (which, as I understand it, is equivalent to a $\Pi_2^0$ statement in KP)?  If any case, what would be a good resource for me to learn more?

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood your proposal in the case of ZFC, since I had thought you were only adding arithmetic assertions, but $V=L$ is not arithmetic. Do you intend to add $\Pi^0_n$ statements now in the Levy hierarchy, rather than the arithmetic hiearchy?

Comment: The Levy hierarchy.

Comment: Ah, then my remark about $\omega$-model should be corrected. One thing that we can say is that if in the background theory we have ZFC relative to a truth predicate for first-order truth (and this is provable in Kelley-Morse set theory), so that we can refer to first-order truth, then your theory will again be a stratification of first-order truth, by essentially the same argument as in the PA case.

Comment: This last comment of mine is not quite right, if one is referring to $\Pi^0_1$ sentences in the language of set theory, in the Levy hierarchy. The reason is that every arithmetic assertion is $\Delta^0_1$ in set theory, since the arithmetic quantifiers are bounded by  $\omega$. Thus, $T_1$ is already inconsistent, since we will add both the Rosser sentence and its negation.

Answer (score 0):

No. It works with T0 and Π01 sentences, as PA refutes any false Π01 sentence. But not so with T1 and Π02 sentences: there are false Π02 sentences which are independent of T1.

Comment: Although there are false $\Pi^0_2$ sentences that are independent of PA, there are no such sentences that are independent of $T_1$, and this is what I proved in my answer. If $\forall x\ \phi(x)$ is a $\Pi^0_2$ sentence that is consistent with $T_1$, then $\phi(m)$ must hold for every standard $m$, since otherwise $\neg\phi(m)$ would be a true $\Pi^0_1$ sentence, making it part of $T_1$ and preventing $\forall x\ \phi(x)$ from being consistent with $T_1$. So $\forall x\ \phi(x)$ is true.

Comment: Hi Panu, welcome to MO.  $\LaTeX$-like math formatting works here; just enclose math in `$` signs. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for more details.

Comment: I beg to differ. There are true $\Sigma_2^0$ sentences which are not provable even in $T_1$.

Comment: @PanuRaatikainen How is that the case? If $\varphi=\exists x\forall y\theta(x, y)$ (with $\theta$ using only bounded quantifiers) is a true $\Sigma^0_2$ sentence, then - for some numeral $n$ - the sentence "$\forall y(\theta(n, y))$" is true. But this is a true $\Pi^0_1$ sentence, hence in $T_1$ (since every $\Pi^0_1$ sentence independent of $PA$ is true). So $T_1$ proves "$\forall y(\theta(n, y))$," so $T_1$ proves "$\exists x\forall y(\theta(x, y))$." Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PanuRaatikainen I've just been reminded (very circuitously) of this answer. Per my and Joel's comments, are you sure this is correct?